# The Relativity of Simultaneity and its Impact on "Seeing" Events

Tags: special-relativity

Will the rocket really see the supernova L first for sure?

The position of the rocket is not specific. We just know that it is at the left of the galaxy. We know that R will explode first in the rocket's frame.

Maybe the galaxy could be moving fast enough so that the time it takes for L to explode is enough for the rocket to see R's light first. In other words, in the time delay L explodes after R, maybe the galaxy could go past the rocket (end up to the left of the rocket). If the galaxy ends up to the left of the rocket and L explodes after that, then R is for sure the first light that the rocket sees.

[image]

Comment: I think some people do not understand what I am asking. If the spaceship is going SUPER SUPER FAST (0.99999c), then, the light from supernova R will have difficulty catching up with the speed of the planet in the perspective of the rocket. THIS will take a lot of time. By THAT time, supernova L, which still has not exploded, is now located to the LEFT of the rocket. SO, R WILL BE SEEN FIRST.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the frame of the galaxy, the supernovas go off at the same time, and both travel towards the rocket at the same speed of c, so since L was closer to the rocket than R at the moment each exploded in this frame, it naturally follows that this frame *must* predict the light from L reaches the rocket before the light from R. Since the rocket's clock is always ticking forward in this frame (although it is running slow due to time dilation), this means we can predict in this frame that the time on the rocket's own clock when the light from L hits it will be earlier than the time on its clock when the light from R hits it.

A key point to understand here is that *all frames must agree in their predictions about local events*, like what times two clocks read at the moment they pass right next to one another, or what time a given clock reads when the light signal from a distant event reaches it. If this wasn't the case, then different reference frames would be more like parallel universes that would predict totally different events. For example, say the you have a clock and light sensor connected to a bomb, designed so that the bomb will explode if the sensor detects a flash of light at a particular chosen time, but if it receives light at any other time the bomb won't be set off. If different frames didn't agree about local events like what time a clock reads when some flash of light hits it, they could in this case disagree about whether the bomb exploded, and about whether the observer standing next to it was alive or dead! Different reference frames are just intended to be different ways of assigning position and time coordinates to the same set of events, nothing more.

So, if we can predict in the galaxy frame the readings of the clock on the rocket at the moments the light from each supernova reaches it, then *all* frames must predict the same things about these local events, including the rest frame of the rocket itself. Therefore it is still predicted in the frame of the rocket that the light from L reaches the rocket first, despite the fact R exploded at an earlier time-coordinate than L in the rocket's frame.

Also, one can use the same principle to say that if the rocket observer has telescopes pointed both to the right (the rocket's nose) and the left (the rocket's tail), then all frames must agree about *which* of these two telescopes the light from supernova L strikes. So since the galaxy frame would predict the light from L would strike the right telescope, this must be a frame-independent fact predicted by all frames--so your argument in a comment that in the rocket frame, by the time the light from R has reached the rocket "supernova L, which still has not exploded, is now located to the LEFT of the rocket", cannot be correct.

Answer (score 0):

If you see it in time reversal and from the point of reference on the rocket, this problem becomes exactly the  standard example of [The train-and-platform thought experiment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativity_of_simultaneity) used to show the relativity of simultaneity. Thus the time reversed guy in the rocket sees the light exiting the planet to reach L first. Which, reversing the movie back in time, means that it left from R first. As you stated in the question (?).

**Another way to see it:** the rocket sees that the 3 bodies move to the left, thus the planets moves towards L and moves way from R (but always keeping the same distances between them). If light left both stars  simultaneosly, the light from L will reach the planet first, because the speed of light is a constant and the planet moves towards the light that left from L.  In order to see the light to get the planet simultaneously (in that he has to agree with the people in the planet), the light from R must leave first, because teh planet moves away from the light that left from R.

Note: neither the speed (0.5c or 0.99c) nore the position of the rocket (left or right of the galaxy) are relevant

Comment: I still do not understand. Let's take the limiting case where the rocket is right above the L supernova at the beginning.

Let's look at it from the perspective of the astronaut. The galaxy is moving to the left at 0.999c. R explodes first. But, because the galaxy is moving  so fast, the light from R takes a lot of time to reach the planet. So, by the time R arrives, the planet is to the left of the rocket. Then the rocket must have seen R first.

Comment: @yolo123 I updted my answer, I hope this helps.

Comment: I understand what you wrote. Please read what I wrote above. I want to see the case where the spaceship is on top of the supernova L. If it is on top of it at the moment R explodes, there is the possibility that the light from R reaches the spaceship first.

Comment: The three objects will move to the left of the rocket. NOW, the rocket will be to the RIGHT OF THE THREE OBJECTS. (I don't know how to make comments bold; please note I am not angry.)

Comment: It doesnt really matter where the ship is relative to the supernovas, that data is irrelevant. It only matters the velociti direction, because the important key to decide simultaneity is if the light reached or left from both bodies simultaneoulsy, and this observation from the rocket does not change with its position (such is if it is closer to R or to L, or to the right or left of the rocket). I'll try to upload a graph

Comment: Yes, but the question asks, which supernova the rockets SEES first. It does not ask for which light exploded first.

Comment: My interpretationis that the question asks  what supernoava   expodes first in your reference frame.  Why do you mean by "which supernova the rockets SEES first", sound a little vague to me. Before the explosion he will always see both stars out there

Comment: Which supernova will he see explode first?